# Store Complex numbers as real and imaginary part separately

Tags: c++, performance, storage, complex-numbers, eigen3

for educational purposes I try to write my own Linear Algebra Library (comparable to Eigen maybe) and I am searching for a good way to store the numbers. I read that Eigen stores them in an array which is created on the heap and then referenced by a storage class. When I tried to look at performance, creation of said array (of size 10000000 elements) is quite fast, comparable with the performance of Eigen, when I use double, float or int as data types. When I use complex or other types, it takes forever to initialize an array of that size, while Eigen has almost no overhead.

Therefore: I would like to try to store real part and imaginary part separately. But when I create a class which does the storing of the numbers for me, I would love to overload the bracket-operator to access the elements. With

```
template<typename nt>
std::complex<nt> operator[](int a){
return std::complex<nt>(realpart[a],imagpart[a]);
}
```

I could return a complex number, but cannot use `a[4]=std::complex<nt>(1,3)` as assignment of an element. When I store my elements in a complex array I can use a reference to make the assignment work, like this:

```
template<typename nt>
&std::complex<nt> operator[](int a){
return numbers[a];
}
```

Is there a way to return the complex number with the bracket but make the assignment work? How does Eigen handle this? And why does creating a complex array have so much overhead compared to normal numbers?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"why does creating a complex array have so much overhead compared to normal numbers?"* Presumably this is because an allocation of an int-array does not initialize any of the elements, but allocation of a `std::complex` array requires invoking the default constructor of each element. It takes longer because the contents of the array are initialized.

Comment: okay, this explains why there is such a big performance difference. Where does this come from? Is it because int, float etc are fundamental types in C++, while complex numbers are not?

Comment: Declaring/allocating an array with no initializer causes each element to be default-initialized. For non-POD class types (as `std::complex<nt>` is), default-initialization is done by calling a constructor that accepts no arguments. Other values are _not_ initialized at all during default-initialization. The concept of "fundamental type" is not really relevant. You can create user-defined types that are also not default-initialized (since C++11) or types for which default-initialization does nothing (in all C++ dialects that I know of).

Comment: Eigen stores complexes in their natural interleaved format. If you want to assign a `std::complex` to two de-interleaved arrays, you need to return a proxy-object, which overloads `operator=(std::complex<T> const&)` (and I'd also overload `operator std::complex<T>()`)